# Cytoscape event cxttap called multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cytoscape.js, cytoscape-web

I am trying to create a network workflow with Cytoscape and AngularJS 1.6
After creating two nodes, user is able to create an edge between them. For this I am using `cy.on('cxttap')` cytoscape function to detect right clicks on both the nodes and then insert a new edge. 
This works fine. Until I added a new view, where the user can see saved workflows from the database. The problem is, if I open the Viewing tab and then go back to creation tab, the `cy.on('cxttap')` function is called twice, and two edges are inserted on the cytoscape canvas, but only one entry is made in my scope variable. I used to have the same factory for both the views but now I am using different angular factories for each.

If I open switch between these tabs multiple times, the number of times I open the viewing tab, is the number of times the function is called, hence more the number of lines.

Here (https://jsfiddle.net/y47kwpg7/4/) is the snippet with the code for both my views with their controllers. "Creation View" --> "MlalTextWorkflowGeneratorCtrl" and "Viewing View" --> "MlalTextWorkflowViewerCtrl".

(Please forgive me, I don't know how to make it work in a single file)

The factory I have here is for the cytoscape canvas, and have a similar one for another view, but with a different id selection.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@maxkfranz 's answer guided me to do a little more debugging and finally I found out the problem.

The problem was I had some listener functions that I called from my controller in order to detect events on the cytoscape nodes. And the listeners to fire were stored in a a variable workflowGraph.listeners. you can see the old code [][1](https://jsfiddle.net/y47kwpg7/3/). The problem was this variable was not emptied anytime my controller was reloaded, because I was calling the listeners from my controller, they were being added to this variable once again. So, one listener had multiple functions to call.

The method I used to solve this was to create a new "listener" type function I had earlier for cytoscape events, which I would call everytime my controller is loaded, to empty the listeners variable for my cytoscape factory.

**In cytoscape factory**

```
    workflowGraph.reinitialize = function () {
        workflowGraph.listeners = {};
    };
```

**In controller**

`workflowCreation` is the name of the factory

```
  workflowCreation.reinitialize();
```

This would simply empty the listeners variable from the factory.

**Remember to call this in your controller after cytoscape initialisation and before calling any other listener functions**

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

You either need to

(1) remove old listeners if you're re-using an instance, or

(2) create a new instance each time you create a new view.

Comment: I am creating a new instance everytime I create a new view, but the problem I recognised is that the listeners are being readded, any inputs how can I remove the old listeners before leaving the view?